# How are ARMv7 assembly opcodes and operands stored in bytes?

Tags: disassembly, arm

I've been trying to analyze an ARM binary but cannot figure out how the operators and operands are stored in the bytes of a program.

For example, by looking at the disassembly listing of an ARMv7 binary,  I cannot deduce what the opcode for `cmp` is from these three lines, nor do I understand how it's encoded or how it's operands are encoded:

```
cmp r5, #0; 0x2d00
cmp r4, #0; 0x2c00
cmp r0, r2; 0x4290
```

How is the `cmp` operator, and it's respective operands encoded into two bytes?

Comment: I've tried comparing the bits using `print "{:16b}\n{:16b}\n{:16b}".format(0x2d00,0x2c00,0x4290)` in Python, and I can't see a pattern emerging for `cmp`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See [ARM7 Data Sheet](http://lars.nocrew.org/computers/processors/ARM/ARM7/manual.pdf) 
4.4 Data processing page 23.
But there will be the different encoding of the instruction depending on the instruction set (ARM or Thumb). See also this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10638130/what-is-the-arm-thumb-instruction-set)

Comment: That clears up the confusion I was having, as I now know how the bits affect the operator.